# 413: Request Entity Too Large error on IIS webservice

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've read other threads and they all point to setting the uploadReadAheadSize and maxRequestEntityAllowed.

I've set maxRequestEntityAllowed to 4294967295 and uploadReadAheadSize to 2147483647 through Configuration Editor but it still isn't working.

I'm sending a 718kb file that was converted to base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added `maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760"` to my binding:

```
<binding name="SecureWebBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
    <security mode="Transport"></security>
</binding>
```

In my Web.config on the server.